# How to build the sample code downloaded from Github

Tags: android, github, gradle, android-studio

env: Mac OS X, Android Studio. (The env should be ok, since I can create new project within Android Studio and build pass with gradle.)

I have searched over the net and tried for several hours, but still not success.

For example this project: https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView.

After download the zip file and extract, in Android Studio select menu "Import project...", then choose extracted file /sample/build.gradle. Android Studio popup an error msg says "Gradle settings for this project is not configured yet. Would you like the project to use the Gradle wrapper? ...". No matter I choose default Yes or No, I always can not build pass.

After some changes, the build.gradle becomes like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 21
    buildToolsVersion = '21.1.1'
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

still cannot build pass, error: "Error:Gradle version 2.1 is required. Current version is 2.0. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/dejian/Downloads/Android-SlideExpandableListView-master/sample/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.1-all.zip."...

Am I in wrong direction? I was assuming the code can be built without any changes. Can anybody teach me how to build with Android Studio? Thanks.

PS, I saw the video demonstrating how to do with Eclipse, but not Android Studio.

Comment: That project hasn't been updated in a long time, and the Gradle Android plugin and Android Studio have undergone massive changes since then (both aren't 1.0 yet). I wouldn't expect the code to build in today's Android Studio without changes. First thing to do is to upgrade Gradle as indicated in the error message.

Comment: Did you try adding the library as a gradle dependency to your project?

Comment: The error message seems to be wrong, because gradle-wrapper.properties is already using gradle 2.1. Without any change, I run command line "./gradlew wrapper", the error msg in Terminal is "Project with path ':library' could not be found in root project 'sample'". Can you please tell me how to 'add'? Thanks. When I "import module" and select "library" folder, Android Studio complains there is already a module named library.